# PJSIP build error for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was building PJSIP step by step according by [iPhone](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone),but when I build project in Xcode, I received some error like:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_RGB24ToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ABGRToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I422ToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBScale", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ABGRToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_YUY2ToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_UYVYToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I422ToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_RGB24ToI420", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420ToABGR", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToRGB24", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_UYVYToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToUYVY", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToYUY2", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_YUY2ToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToABGR", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420ToRGB24", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420ToYUY2", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420ToUYVY", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_ARGBToI422", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420ToARGB", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>         _conv_to_bgra in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420Rotate", referenced from:
>         _pjmedia_vid_dev_conv_resize_and_rotate in libpjmedia-videodev.a(util.o)
>     "_I420ToI422", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>     "_I420Scale", referenced from:
>         _conv_from_i420 in libpjmedia.a(converter_libyuv.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I checked libpjmedia.a with *lipo -info* it does support arm64. I am so confused after work on it for two days, wish you can help, THX.

What's in my config_site.h

> #define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
>   #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1
>   #include "pj/config_site_sample.h"

Environment: Xcode 7.3
Device: iPhone 6p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link libyuv.a to your project.